# Sympy вывод подробного решения

Tags: python, sympy

Можно ли в `Python` из `Sympy` вывести подробное решение производных сложных функций?

Answer (score 4):

Мечта студента) 
Вообще производные в таком ПО вычисляются как правило численными методами, не аналитически, особенно если вычисляются производные сложных функций. В этом случае пошаговое решение может показать только странные функции, которые умножаются на странные константы, что в итоге приводит к верному результату.

Что касается sympy - насколько я понял, в самой библиотеке вывод пошагового решения [пока не предусмотрен](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/11088), но у этой компании есть продукт который показывает шаги решения - http://www.sympygamma.com/. Незнаю, решение насколько сложных функции он может показать.

Посмотрите также в сторону [wolfram alpha](http://wolframalpha.com) и [wolfram mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica)

Ну и добавлю от себя - если вам нужна конкретная цифра, решение, то используете численные методы. Если вам нужно аналитическое решение - то лучше изучить методы решения производных, они не такие сложные.