# алгоритм для вычисления символьных выражений

Tags: алгоритм, любой-язык

Смысл алгоритма заключается в том, чтобы он выражал из какой либо формулы какую либо величину(не важно какую). Например формула S=v*t и нужно выразить из неё например t чтобы тало так t=S/v. но формула может быть и сложной. Нет ли какого либо алгоритма для таких случаев.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример реализации такого алгоритма содержит библиотека [**`sympy`**](https://sympy.org/ru/) (язык [`Python`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python)):

```
from sympy import solve, sympify, Symbol

# решаем уравнение x * a = b относительно переменной x
# уравнение можно переписать в виде x * a - b = 0
equation = sympify('x * a - b')

x = Symbol('x')
solution = solve(equation, x)
print(solution)

# выведет [ b/a ]
```

Некоторые ссылки:

- [Похожий вопрос](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/294022/483853) на math.stackexchange.com
- [Похожий вопрос](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/9538) на cs.stackexchange.com
- [Похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3637909/5812238) на stackoverflow.com
- [Связанный вопрос про `sympy`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/673642/227016)
- Документация функции [`solve`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html#sympy.solvers.solvers.solve) в `sympy`
- Онлайн сервис [WolframAlpha](https://wolframalpha.com/), умеющий решать [такие](https://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%20*%20a%20%3D%20b) и многие другие уравнения

Comment: а в языке java нет такого метода?

Comment: @DAVID встроенного думаю нету, но я уверен что существует библиотека для Java позволяющая делать что-то похожее